# Webservice and soap

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I  try to configure a shipping expedition but I have an error on WSI2_RecherchePointRelais.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method soapclient::WSI2_RecherchePointRelais()
```

Link  : to access the api https://api.mondialrelay.com/Web_Services.asmx?WSDL

One of result of this :

```
$webservice = 'https://api.mondialrelay.com/Web_Services.asmx?WSDL';
$client = new \SoapClient($webservice, 'WSDL');
```

is

```
["wsdlFile"]=> string(51) "https://api.mondialrelay.com/Web_Services.asmx?WSDL" ["wsdl"]=> NULL
```

I don't know if the error is here.

Thank you

the php code

```
    $statCode = [];
    $params =[];
    $params['Enseigne'] = $enseigne;
    $params['Poids'] = round($this->shipping_weight * 1000);
    $params['Taille'] = '';
    $params['CP'] = '75000'; 
    $params['Ville'] = 'Paris';
    $params['Pays'] =  'FR';
    $params['Action'] = '';
    $params['RayonRecherche'] = '';
    $concat = $params['Enseigne'] . $params['Pays'] . $params['Ville'] . $params['CP'] . $params['Poids'] . $this->privateKey;
    $params['Security'] = strtoupper(md5($concat));

    $result_mr = $client->WSI2_RecherchePointRelais($params);
```

example of params

```
["Enseigne"]=> string(8) "BDTESTMR" 
["Poids"]=> float(3300) 
["Taille"]=> string(0) "" 
["CP"]=> string(5) "75000" 
["Ville"]=> string(5) "Paris" 
["Pays"]=> string(2) "FR" 
["Action"]=> string(0) "" 
["RayonRecherche"]=> string(0) "" 
["Security"]=> string(32) "263C1BEF52C37A444B93A62A3F297955"
```

response

```
object(soapclient)#68 (48) { ["username"]=> string(0) "" ["password"]=> string(0) "" ["authtype"]=> string(0) "" ["certRequest"]=> array(0) { } ["requestHeaders"]=> bool(false) ["responseHeaders"]=> string(0) "" ["responseHeader"]=> NULL ["document"]=> string(0) "" ["endpoint"]=> string(51) "https://api.mondialrelay.com/Web_Services.asmx?WSDL" ["forceEndpoint"]=> string(0) "" ["proxyhost"]=> bool(false) ["proxyport"]=> bool(false) ["proxyusername"]=> bool(false) ["proxypassword"]=> bool(false) ["portName"]=> string(0) "" ["xml_encoding"]=> string(0) "" ["http_encoding"]=> bool(false) ["timeout"]=> int(0) ["response_timeout"]=> int(30) ["endpointType"]=> string(4) "soap" ["persistentConnection"]=> bool(false) ["defaultRpcParams"]=> bool(false) ["request"]=> string(0) "" ["response"]=> string(0) "" ["responseData"]=> string(0) "" ["cookies"]=> array(0) { } ["decode_utf8"]=> bool(true) ["operations"]=> array(0) { } ["curl_options"]=> array(0) { } ["bindingType"]=> string(0) "" ["use_curl"]=> bool(false) ["fault"]=> NULL ["faultcode"]=> NULL ["faultstring"]=> NULL ["faultdetail"]=> NULL ["title"]=> string(6) "NuSOAP" ["version"]=> string(5) "0.9.5" ["revision"]=> string(18) "$Revision: 1.123 $" ["error_str"]=> string(0) "" ["debug_str"]=> string(279) "2018-11-25 23:19:20.592941 soapclient: ctor wsdl= timeout=0 response_timeout=30 endpoint=string(51) "https://api.mondialrelay.com/Web_Services.asmx?WSDL" 2018-11-25 23:19:20.592959 soapclient: instantiate SOAP with endpoint at https://api.mondialrelay.com/Web_Services.asmx?WSDL " ["charencoding"]=> bool(true) ["debugLevel"]=> int(9) ["XMLSchemaVersion"]=> string(32) "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ["soap_defencoding"]=> string(10) "ISO-8859-1" ["namespaces"]=> array(4) { ["SOAP-ENV"]=> string(41) "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ["xsd"]=> string(32) "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ["xsi"]=> string(41) "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ["SOAP-ENC"]=> string(41) "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" } ["usedNamespaces"]=> array(0) { } ["typemap"]=> array(6) { ["http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"]=> array(43) { ["string"]=> string(6) "string" ["boolean"]=> string(7) "boolean" ["float"]=> string(6) "double" ["double"]=> string(6) "double" ["decimal"]=> string(6) "double" ["duration"]=> string(0) "" ["dateTime"]=> string(6) "string" ["time"]=> string(6) "string" ["date"]=> string(6) "string" ["gYearMonth"]=> string(0) "" ["gYear"]=> string(0) "" ["gMonthDay"]=> string(0) "" ["gDay"]=> string(0) "" ["gMonth"]=> string(0) "" ["hexBinary"]=> string(6) "string" ["base64Binary"]=> string(6) "string" ["anyType"]=> string(6) "string" ["anySimpleType"]=> string(6) "string" ["normalizedString"]=> string(6) "string" ["token"]=> string(6) "string" ["language"]=> string(0) "" ["NMTOKEN"]=> string(0) "" ["NMTOKENS"]=> string(0) "" ["Name"]=> string(0) "" ["NCName"]=> string(0) "" ["ID"]=> string(0) "" ["IDREF"]=> string(0) "" ["IDREFS"]=> string(0) "" ["ENTITY"]=> string(0) "" ["ENTITIES"]=> string(0) "" ["integer"]=> string(7) "integer" ["nonPositiveInteger"]=> string(7) "integer" ["negativeInteger"]=> string(7) "integer" ["long"]=> string(7) "integer" ["int"]=> string(7) "integer" ["short"]=> string(7) "integer" ["byte"]=> string(7) "integer" ["nonNegativeInteger"]=> string(7) "integer" ["unsignedLong"]=> string(0) "" ["unsignedInt"]=> string(0) "" ["unsignedShort"]=> string(0) "" ["unsignedByte"]=> string(0) "" ["positiveInteger"]=> string(0) "" } ["http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema"]=> array(11) { ["i4"]=> string(0) "" ["int"]=> string(7) "integer" ["boolean"]=> string(7) "boolean" ["string"]=> string(6) "string" ["double"]=> string(6) "double" ["float"]=> string(6) "double" ["dateTime"]=> string(6) "string" ["timeInstant"]=> string(6) "string" ["base64Binary"]=> string(6) "string" ["base64"]=> string(6) "string" ["ur-type"]=> string(5) "array" } ["http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"]=> array(11) { ["i4"]=> string(0) "" ["int"]=> string(7) "integer" ["boolean"]=> string(7) "boolean" ["string"]=> string(6) "string" ["double"]=> string(6) "double" ["float"]=> string(6) "double" ["dateTime"]=> string(6) "string" ["timeInstant"]=> string(6) "string" ["base64Binary"]=> string(6) "string" ["base64"]=> string(6) "string" ["ur-type"]=> string(5) "array" } ["http://soapinterop.org/xsd"]=> array(1) { ["SOAPStruct"]=> string(6) "struct" } ["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"]=> array(3) { ["base64"]=> string(6) "string" ["array"]=> string(5) "array" ["Array"]=> string(5) "array" } ["http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "Map" } } ["xmlEntities"]=> array(5) { ["quot"]=> string(1) """ ["amp"]=> string(1) "&" ["lt"]=> string(1) "<" ["gt"]=> string(1) ">" ["apos"]=> string(1) "'" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the class instantiation line to this:

```
$client = new SoapClient($webservice); // remove the second parameter
```

The second construct parameter is supposed to be an array containing connection options. If there isn't any, just remove it.